# How to dynamically show photos after importing them by user in angular 5?

Tags: angular, image, typescript, angular-cli, property-binding

I am trying to understand some features of angular bei doing this small example.

from `<input type="file">` the user selects an **image-file**. Then HttpClient sends post request to the backend(nodejs) to save the selected image-file to the folder `src/assets/images` within my Angular 5 web application. Till now everything works perfectly.

**My Experiment**

I would like to show the *imported* image in a `div` below that input field.

**Problem**

I get

[image]

In spite of that `IMG2.jpg` was successfully added to `src/assets/images` via the backend.

**My Questions**

1. How to force `ng serve` senses the backend changes applied on angular-app files-structure?
2. Is it a good practice to use such markup `<img [src]="img.path"> <!-- my variable in component.ts -->`?

I am using angular5, angular-cli: 1.5.4, typescript ~2.4.2, OSX 10.13.2, node 8.9.1, npm 5.5.1.

Thank you in advance.

**If you are interested in seeing my code**

*component.ts:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'screenshot',
  templateUrl: './screenshot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./screenshot.component.css']
})
export class ScreenshotComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('images') images: any[] = [];
  fileInput: HTMLInputElement;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // the magic was brought to you from 
  https://gist.github.com/aitoribanez/8b2d38601f6916139f5754aae5bcc15f

  filesToUpload: any[] = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * this will be called, wenn the button "Einfuegen" is clicked!
   */

  upload(form: HTMLFormElement) {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const files: Array<any> = this.filesToUpload;

  formData.append("uploads", files[0], files[0]['name']);
  console.log(formData);
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/upload', formData)
    .subscribe(files => {
      console.log('files', files)
      this.images.push({
        name: files[0].filename,
        path: "assets/images/" + files[0].filename
      });
    console.log("images list", this.images);
    })
// To reset the input field
    this.fileInput.value = "";
  }

  fileChangeEvent(event: any) {
      this.filesToUpload = event.srcElement.files;
      console.log(this.filesToUpload);
      this.fileInput = event.srcElement;
   }

  }
```

*component.html*

```
<div>
    <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
    <button type="submit">Eingfuegen!</button>

  <div [(ngModel)]="images" *ngIf="images.length > 0" name="displayImages" ngDefaultControl>
    <div class="myphoto" *ngFor="let img of images">
      <img [src]="img.path" alt="{{img.name}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you log ‘files’ to the console does the file show up?

Comment: yes, it does, here is the log:
`files 
[{…}]
0
:
destination
:
"./../src/assets/images"
encoding
:
"7bit"
fieldname
:
"uploads"
filename
:
"test3.png"
mimetype
:
"image/png"
originalname
:
"test3.png"
path
:
"../src/assets/images/test3.png"
size
:
10086
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found the solution.

**Source** of problem was the delay of the IO, namely the hard disk, though it is a SSD in my case!

The **solution** was -- though I changed the markup a little bit -- to add a `setTimeout()` function in the `subscribe` of the Http-request in `upload()` function.

It is not a clean way, but it works for the mean time.